# Fill large number of rows with sequential data in Excel

Tags: excel, sequential

My goal here is to fill around 500000 rows with the data using this formula

```
 =60 + RAND()*40
```

I have generated around 20 rows using this formula but do not know a quicker way to fill a large number of rows (say 500000) If I use autofill it does not follow the command and instead sequentially increases.
I would like the numbers to stay below 100, as per the formula.

[image]

I would like to generate around 500000 rows with these sequential values following the trend using the formula above. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Name box` to navigate to desired row and then copy your formula.

1. Enter formula in first row
2. Copy
3. Into `Name box` enter desired cell address, press `enter`
4. Then press `Ctrl + Shift + Arrow Up`
5. Paste

[image]